# How to select text with javascript that's not already in a div/span

Tags: javascript

I am using the typing effect shown at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_typewriter.asp. However, I want to change it a bit by making the word "effect!" text blue.

The problem is, I don't know how to select text that is not wrapped in an html element like a span/div already. I don't think javascript/css can select individual characters so I tried injecting a  tag during in the if statement but the browser seems to automatically close any span tag left open. Not sure where to go from here.

Original code from W3

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum typing effect!'; /* The text */
var speed = 50; /* The speed/duration of the effect in milliseconds */

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
```

My code

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum typing effect!'; /* The text */
var speed = 50; /* The speed/duration of the effect in milliseconds */

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  if (i == 20) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += '<span>';
  if (i == 26) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += '</span>';
}
```

I would like to get "Lorem ipsum typing effect!" with "effect!" wrapped in a span so I can change that text to blue. i.e. `"Lorem ipsum typing <span style='color:blue;'>effect!</span>"`

Comment: Great first question.  I would point you in the direction of looking at regex patterns for string manipulation. For example Great first question.  I would point you in the direction of looking at regex patterns for string manipulation.  Regex101.com is a great resource.  You could do something like this: `const result = ("Lorem ipsum typing effect!").replace(/(.+)(effect)(.+)/gm, `\1<span style='color:blue;'>\2</span>\3`);`

Answer (score 1):

Use replace to find and swap the entire string you're looking for. This will not be visible until the entire word is visible though.

```
if (i == 26) {
    var txt = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
    txt.replace("effect!", "<span style='color:blue;'>effect!</span>");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt
}
```

If you want it "as you go", you need to wrap the span around each character when `i` is between 20 and 26 as part of adding it to he DIV.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<span style='color:blue;'>" + txt.charAt(i) + "</span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some manipulation with the txt variable before injecting it into the innerHTML. Here's the complete code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <h1>Typewriter</h1>
    
    <button onclick="typeWriter()">Click me</button>
    
    <p id="demo"></p>
    
    <script>
    
    var i = 0;
    var txt = 'Lorem ipsum typing effect!'; /* The text */
    var speed = 50; /* The speed/duration of the effect in milliseconds */
    
    function typeWriter() {
      if (i < txt.length) {
       var innerHTML = txt.substr(0, Math.min(i+1, 19));
        if (i >= 20) {
         innerHTML += '<span style="color:blue;">' + txt.substr(19, i - 18) + '</span>';
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = innerHTML;
        
        i++;
        setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
      }
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```